# How to pass java.util.Date to Java library with help of php-java bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

Im using javabridge to connect php to jasper reports and Im trying to pass two parameters but I get warnings and errors

```
Warning: Unchecked exception detected: [[o:Response$UndeclaredThrowableErrorMarker]:"FATAL: Undeclared java.lang.RuntimeException detected. java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new java.util.Date((o:String)[o:String]). Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException VM: 1.7.0_79@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-10 java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source) #-9 java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source) #-8 sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source) #-7 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessor[...]/java/Java.inc(361): java_Arg->getResult(false) #2 http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc(364): java_Client->getWrappedResult(false) #3 http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc(536): java_Client->getInternalResult() #4 http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc(1930): java_Client->createObject('java.util.Date', Array) #5 C:\wamp\www\advanced\backend\javabridge\generate.php(49): Java->Java('java.util.Date', '12/Feb/16') #6 {main}] in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc on line 202

 Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[c:JasperFillManager]]->fillReport((o:JasperReport)[o:JasperReport], (i:Map)[o:HashMap], (i:Connection)[o:Connection]). Cause: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Incompatible php.java.bridge.Response$UndeclaredThrowableErrorMarker value assigned to parameter FInicio in the Reubicados dataset. VM: 1.7.0_79@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-16 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameter(JRFillDataset.java:903) #-15 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setFillParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:642) #-14 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:585) #-13 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1280) #-12 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:901) #-11 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845) #-10 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58) #-9 net.sf.jas in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

The problem is when it tries to create java.util.Date instance. Here´s php file:

```
   <?php


    require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc");

    try {   
        $Param1 = date('d/M/y', strtotime($_POST['FInicio']));
        $Param2 = date('d/M/y', strtotime($_POST['FFin']));



        $jasperxml = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader");
        $jasperDesign = $jasperxml->load(realpath("Reubicados.jrxml"));
        $query = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery");

        $jasperDesign->setQuery($query);
        $compileManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
        $report = $compileManager->compileReport($jasperDesign); } catch (JavaException $ex) {
        echo $ex; }


    $fillManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager"); //aqui se pasan los parametros (Fecha Inicio y Fecha Fin) 
$params = new Java("java.util.HashMap"); 
$date=new Java('java.util.Date',$Param1);
$date1=new Java('java.util.Date',$Param2); 
$params->put("FInicio",$date); 
$params->put("FFin",$date1);



    $class = new JavaClass("java.lang.Class"); $class->forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); $driverManager = new JavaClass("java.sql.DriverManager");

    //db username and password 
$conn = $driverManager->getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/viajestrafico?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "root"); $jasperPrint = $fillManager->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);

    $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter");
```

And sql query in ireports:

```
SELECT
     ayudante_situacion_laboral.`FechaInicio` AS ayudante_situacion_laboral_FechaInicio,
     ayudante_situacion_laboral.`FechaFin` AS ayudante_situacion_laboral_FechaFin,
     ayudante_situacion_laboral.`Cant_Horas` AS ayudante_situacion_laboral_Cant_Horas,
     ayudante_situacion_laboral.`Descripcion` AS ayudante_situacion_laboral_Descripcion,
     ayudante.`Registro` AS ayudante_Registro,
     ayudante.`Nombre` AS ayudante_Nombre,
     situacion_laboral.`Estado` AS situacion_laboral_Estado
FROM
     `ayudante` ayudante INNER JOIN `ayudante_situacion_laboral` ayudante_situacion_laboral ON ayudante.`Ayudante_ID` = ayudante_situacion_laboral.`AyudanteAyudante_ID`
     INNER JOIN `situacion_laboral` situacion_laboral ON ayudante_situacion_laboral.`Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID` = situacion_laboral.`SitL_ID`
WHERE
     situacion_laboral.Estado = 'Reubicado'  and $P{FInicio}<= ayudante_situacion_laboral.`FechaInicio` and $P{FFin}>=ayudante_situacion_laboral.`FechaFin`
UNION

     SELECT
     chofer_situacion_laboral.`FechaInicio` AS chofer_situacion_laboral_FechaInicio,
     chofer_situacion_laboral.`FechaFin` AS chofer_situacion_laboral_FechaFin,
     chofer_situacion_laboral.`Cant_Horas` AS chofer_situacion_laboral_Cant_Horas,
     chofer_situacion_laboral.`Descripcion` AS chofer_situacion_laboral_Descripcion,
     chofer.`Registro` AS chofer_Registro,
     chofer.`Nombre` AS chofer_Nombre,
     situacion_laboral.`Estado` AS situacion_laboral_Estado
FROM
     `chofer` chofer INNER JOIN `chofer_situacion_laboral` chofer_situacion_laboral ON chofer.`Chofer_ID` = chofer_situacion_laboral.`ChoferChofer_ID`
     INNER JOIN `situacion_laboral` situacion_laboral ON chofer_situacion_laboral.`Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID` = situacion_laboral.`SitL_ID`
WHERE
     (situacion_laboral.Estado = 'Reubicado' and $P{FInicio}<= chofer_situacion_laboral.`FechaInicio` and $P{FFin}>=chofer_situacion_laboral.`FechaFin`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple, just a problem I had from the beginning in php code.

```
    $query = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery");

    $jasperDesign->setQuery($query);
```

This code was preventing xrml query from executing, because it was creating a query object empty.

Answer (score 3):

Looking to your error message, the `java.util.Date` cannot be created with '12/Feb/16':

```
java_Client->createObject('java.util.Date', Array) 
#5 C:\wamp\www\advanced\backend\javabridge\generate.php(49): 
Java->Java('java.util.Date', '12/Feb/16') #6 {main}] in
```

---

If you want to **instanciate a java date object**, use the [java.util.Date(long date)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) constructor which accepts a timestamp expressed in milliseconds :

```
<?php
$startDate = $_POST['FInicio'];  // better to filter this :)
$Param1 = strtotime($startDate) * 1000; // to get milliseconds
if ($Param1 == 0) {
   throw new Exception("FInicio date parameter could not be parsed");
}

// ...
$javaDate = new Java('java.util.Date',$Param1); // This is a java date
```

Your `$date` parameter should now be a valid `java.util.Date` object.

**You can test it** :

```
$simpleDateFormat = new Java("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", 'yyyy-MM-dd');
echo $simpleDateFormat->format($javaDate); 
// should print your date in Y-m-d format
```

---

Alternatively, you can parse the date in Java through the `java.text.SimpleDateFormatter` object:

```
$date = '2016-12-21';
$simpleDateFormat = new Java("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", 'yyyy-MM-dd');
$javaDate = $simpleDateFormat->parse($date); // This is a Java date
```

Both approaches works...

---

**JasperReport issue with date**

Not exactly linked to your question, but if you want to use your Date as a query parameter you should use the [java.sql.Date(long date)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)) object instead of java.util.Date... Here's a little *dirty* snippet to summarize changes:

```
// php 

$sqlDate = new Java('java.sql.Date', strtotime($_POST['FInicio']) * 1000));
$params->put('FInicio', $sqlDate);

// in your report header (.jrxml):
<parameter name="FInicio" class="java.sql.Date">

// in your report query (.jrxml):
$P{FInicio} <= chofer_situacion_laboral.`FechaInicio`
```

---

You can also have a look to the [soluble-japha](https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha) javabridge client (refactored Java.inc client), the syntax differs a bit but there's [a documentation about dates](http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/language_basics/#working-with-dates) that might reveal useful.

Comment: Thanks. Im trying the first approach but I need an object formatted as d/M/y to build the query. So I get empty results putting just like that. Any advice?

Comment: Looking at your previous post, you define your dates parameters as 'Date'

Comment: Looking at your previous post, you defined your dates as 'java.util.Date'... If you want to build your query with them, it must be done on the jasper side. If yo want to avoid jasper side, you can always specify your jasper parameters as 'java.lang.String()' and instead of preparaing a date in php, send dates as text.

Comment: Just in case, I've update the solution to include a test for parsing the date. Please have a look to the exception test. It might be the cause and easily debugable. From your previous comment, I don't think you need to format your date object in the query with a jdbc mysql datasource, a simple 'startDate > $P{FInicio}' should work as Jasper knows it's a date. Not sure 100%, but try and see.

Comment: this exception isn´t thrown, so it means that params are sent as date. No errors, but it shows empty .doc report. It´s like jasper doesn´t see it in the proper format.

Comment: I wouldn't think about format problems (jasper handles it, a date is a date). Just updated the solution to include a test for displaying the date you've entered. Test and if the date is the same, we are absolutly sure it's not on the PHP side... then check your jasper query params (i.e. : tableColumnDate > $P{startDate}), ensure there's no ! into param.

Comment: I tested what you proposed and dates are OK. It seems it´s about ireports. Have a look, I´ve updated with sql query.

Comment: can you format the date using another format like date('c', strtotime($_POST['FInicio'])) and if that doesn't work you can always pass it as an integer ( only strtotime($_POST['FInicio']) ) and then construct the date in SQL using the function to_timestamp($P{FInicio})

Comment: Yanet, little update for jasper reports... Try with java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date... Hope it will help, good luck

Comment: Still not working. I can see both dates as : 2/01/16 19:00 and  27/11/16 19:00 in report showing parameters as expressions, but query doesn´t show results in report table

Comment: No luck then, I suspect the query now... Have you tried to hardcode the dates in the query instead of relying on the parameters. Just to be sure that something is returned. I suppose you already tested that. Otherwise send the parameters as 'java.lang.String' (same method as I explained in the change to java.sql.Date, ensure your date parameters are now strings)

Comment: Yes, I hardocoded the date like this: '2016-01-01' and it worked. I tried as string but then I couldn't parse it into date format for query evaluation. I think that the other option (using date format) is more suitable. I only need to know how to change parameters format into 'yyyy-MM-dd', in ireports, and run query with that format.

Comment: Sébastien, I feel Im very closed to the solution. I tested printing both dates after parsing in php                                                                             `$date=new Java('java.sql.Date',$Param1);
$date1=new Java('java.sql.Date',$Param2);
echo($date);
echo($date1);` and it showed the right format: **2016-01-03 2016-12-14. ** But then I checked in ireports, dragging the parameters to the page without changing its default format and here´s what it showed: **3/01/16 19:00 14/12/16 19:00. ** I´m thinking about formatting these parameters in sql...

Comment: @SébastienVanvelthem, please check my comments above and tell me what you propose..

Comment: @SébastienVanvelthem I found the issue but not the solution. I hardcoded  those dates again and tried to run from php and results aren't shown. Although from ireports viewer they are correctly shown. What could it be?

Comment: @YanetPedraza, worth to check that your connection `$conn = $driverManager->getConnection()` is made on the same datasource as the one used in iReport. If not working create a new issue with php-java-bridge and jasperreports tags and provides new details and I'll have a look.